# With the PlayStation website re-design, how can I browse and download PS3 games now?

Tags: ps3, psn

I used to my my computer (with the help of the PSDLE plugin) to browse and download my PS3 games, but with the new website update that doesn't seem to be possible any more - it only lists PS4 and PS5 games.

Is there anywhere I can get them now please? Someone recommended [this link](https://store.playstation.com/en-gb/home/games?PlatformPrivacyWs1=all&psappver=19.15.0&smcid=psapp) but it just takes me to the homepage.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of October 19th, 2020, Sony discontinued web and mobile support for the PS3, PSP, and PS Vita systems. In order to purchase and download content, you must do it through the Playstation Store within the console itself.

> - You will no longer be able to purchase PS3, PSP and PS Vita content, themes or avatars on our Web or Mobile Store.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> Additionally, you will still be able to access your already purchased content from your respective devices.
>
> <sub>[Source](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/important-notice/)</sub>

Comment: Ahhh! Gutted, it was so much easier to do it on the website :( Thank you though.