# When the store for ps3 closes can I still reinstall my games digitally?

Tags: ps3

Like if I bought a game from the PlayStation store and not on disc can I still reinstall my digital games or will I forever lose those games? Also don’t have a usb so I’m kinda also asking if it’s possible to reinstall games if you don’t have a USB handy to reinstall your games?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Sony Support](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/support/important-notice/):

> We are closing PlayStation™Store on PlayStation®3 consoles on 2nd July 2021 [...]
>
> **What features can I use after the closure of PlayStation™Store and purchase functionality on PS3, PS Vita and PSP devices?**
>
> Features you will still be able to access:
>
> - You will still be able to re-download and play previously purchased game titles.
> - [...]
> - You will still be able to re-download and play claimed game titles through PlayStation®Plus as long as you remain a member of the service.

So until Sony decides to change this, **you can still redownload and reinstall games purchased on the PlayStation Store to your PS3** (and PS Vita and PSP).

As for how to do that:

> **How do I access my owned games?**
> You can download your owned content onto your PS3, PS Vita or PSP device by accessing the Download List on the respective device.

Comment: Related: [With the PlayStation website re-design, how can I browse and download PS3 games now?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/380261/124566)